# Delphi - Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted

Tags: sql-server-2005, delphi, ado, delphi-5

This error showed when I tried to select on an empty table in MS SQL Server 2005: "either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted". I have used TADOConnection and TADODataSet in Delphi 5 to connect and retrieve data from the database.

```
  Conn := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  DataSet := TADODataSet.Create(nil);

  Conn.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=sa;' +
                           'Persist Security Info=True;' +
                           'User ID=user;Initial Catalog=mydb;' +
                           'Data Source=MYPC\SQLEXPRESS;' +
                           'Use Procedure for Prepare=1;' +
                           'Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;' +
                           'Workstation ID=MYPC;' +
                           'Use Encryption for Data=False;' +
                           'Tag with column collation when possible=False';
  Conn.LoginPrompt := False;
  Conn.Open;

  DataSet.Connection := Conn;
  DataSet.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE';
  DataSet.Open;

  DataSet.Free;
  Conn.Free;
```

Is there a way to check if a database table is empty without incurring such error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error originally occured with an update to MDAC_TYP (to 2.6 from memory). According to an old [Borland advisory](http://info.borland.com/devsupport/delphi/fixes/delphi5/database.html) 
"This is a bug in the SQL Server provider.   Set 
`CursorLocation = clUseClient` to eliminate the error."

There was a ADOExpress patch available from [Borland](http://info.borland.com/devsupport/delphi/mdac26.html), but the link doesn't work. Embarcadero now host it here: ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/adoexpress/d5adoupdate2.exe(Thanks for the official link Jeroen!)

I would recommend downloading and installing all patches listed on the Embarcadero site, assuming you can find them.

Comment: Edited to add links to official version on Embarcadero's ftp site

Answer (score 6):

Download the ADO update for Delphi 5 here: ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/adoexpress/d5adoupdate2.exe

Make sure you also have the regular update installed:

- [English Enterprise](ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/delphi5/D5EntUpdate.exe)
- [English Professional](ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/delphi5/D5ProUpdate.exe)
- [English Standard](ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/delphi5/D5StdUpdate.exe)

There are more updates (Corba, original ADO install) and languages (French, German), but these should get you going.

There also used to be a http://info.borland.com/devsupport/delphi/download_files/zlibupdate.zip, but it is not on the ftpd servers.

--jeroen

Comment: Thanks, I wonder how you got these links, my Google skills isn't good

Comment: I got it, ftpc.borland.com is now replaced by ftpd.embarcadero.com but all the files and folders are the same

Comment: I get "This update requires that the ADOExpress Update Pack 1 already be installed.". I tried to modify the given download link to 'd5adoupdate1.exe', but that file is not found on the server. Where can I get it?

Comment: Never had that error, and I don't have a VM with Delphi 5 any more. So I presume it means you need to have to first install the normal Enterprise/Professional/Standard update I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I did install that normal delphi pro update. I now reinstalled delphi pro, then the delphi pro udpate, now delphi won't start anymore (runtime error). I do have a German version of delphi 5, so maybe that pro update doesn't work for the German version (even though the first time around I was able to start delphi after the update).

Comment: That might be the case. I never kept track of the international updates. They should be there on the ftpd server, but since it does not allow directory browsing, so I'd start with this: http://ftplike.com/browser/obelix.tul.cz/pub/mirrors/ftp.borland.com/delphi/devsupport/updates/delphi5/german/

Comment: Thanks! I found the german update and I also found the first ADO Express update! The server is case sensitive! As soon as I have time I will post the exact links. I uninstalled delphi 5. Installed again. Then the delhpi pro german update. Then ADO express, then ADO update pack 1, then ADO update pack 2. This cost me the whole day and I probably entered the license key like 30 times. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! The ftp is served by a unix server. Those are case sensitive indeed (:

Answer (score 2):

It was long time agom but I recall that this problem in Delphi 5 resolves by Delphi update. Early version has serious problems with ADO components

P.S. Also I see that your code uses not typical runtime creation of components and does not use some container like data module or form (not good usually) for visual work with components. Also sometimes useful run simple queries via adoConnection.execute. If you do not use visual components, handling of ADO's Recordset object is much the same as Delphi's AdoDataset.

Comment: If you don't use ADO's Recordset object for non-visual code, use `AdoDataSet.DisableControls` to vastly improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Since I spent a whole day on this, here is a wrap up of what I did in the end.

Delphi 5 Pro Installation with ADO Express

1. Uninstall Delphi 5, also deleted installation directory
2. Install Delphi 5 Pro (I only have a German Delphi Pro edition available)
3. Install Delphi 5 Pro Update (I used the German update)
4. Install Delphi 5 ADO Express
5. Install Delphi 5 ADO Express Update Pack 1
6. Install Delphi 5 ADO Express Update Pack 2

And the download links (many thanks again Jeroen Wiert Pluimers):

Delphi 5 Pro updates:

ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/delphi5/D5ProUpdate.exe
ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/delphi5/german/d5proupdate.exe

ADOExpress Update Packs 1 and 2:

ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/adoexpress/D5ADOUpgrade.exe
ftp://ftpd.embarcadero.com/pub/delphi/devsupport/updates/adoexpress/d5adoupdate2.exe

And for future reference some screenshots to build the download links (case sensitive):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]