# EOleException: Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-xe

I get this exception:

**EOleException: Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record**

trying to delete a record:

```
if SetupTable.Locate('MyFieldName', AKey, []) then
  SetupTable.Delete
```

What happens here is that there is a check for if a record in the database exists, and if so it is deleted. My problem  is that the record does exist, but deleting it produces the above exception.

It's a single user setup, and there is no way the record could disappear in between the execution of those two lines.

This code has been running fine for 8 years. The exception only occurs on Windows 8. I've seen it at 5 different customer sites. Customers using Windows XP, Vista, 7 dont see the problem.

I use Delphi XE to access an MS Access database through ADO with provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

here is a stack dump:

```
0073f59d DSALon.exe   ADODB         4712 DoRecordsetDelete
0073f5b6 DSALon.exe   ADODB         4719 TCustomADODataSet.InternalDelete
006b3dd1 DSALon.exe   DB           12947 TDataSet.CheckOperation
006b3ad8 DSALon.exe   DB           12856 TDataSet.Delete
007cade6 DSALon.exe   DatabaseUnit   629 ClearSetup
```

The offending bit of code in ADODB look like this:

```
procedure DoRecordsetDelete(DataSet: TCustomADODataSet; AffectRecords: TAffectRecords);
begin
  with DataSet do
  try
    Recordset.Delete(AffectRecordsValues[AffectRecords]);
    { When CacheSize > 1, Recordset allows fetching of deleted records.
      Calling MovePrevious seems to work around it }
    if (CacheSize > 1) and (PRecInfo(ActiveBuffer).RecordNumber <> 1) then
    begin
      Recordset.MovePrevious;
      Recordset.MoveNext;
    end;
    Recordset.MoveNext;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Recordset.CancelUpdate;
      DatabaseError(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

which leads me to think that the CacheSize is relevant here. I do use a CacheSize > 1.

The MSDN help on ADO CacheSize property says:

*If CacheSize is set to a value greater than one, the navigation methods (Move, MoveFirst, MoveLast, MoveNext, and MovePrevious) may result in navigation to a deleted record, if deletion occurs after the records were retrieved. After the initial fetch, subsequent deletions will not be reflected in your data cache until you attempt to access a data value from a deleted row. However, setting CacheSize to one eliminates this issue since deleted rows cannot be fetched.*

Still, I'm 100% sure that the record that I'm trying to delete isn't already deleted.

But maybe doing a Resync before the Locate might avoid the problem..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi - Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402674/delphi-either-bof-or-eof-is-true-or-the-current-record-has-been-deleted)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The code does check if the record is still there, before trying to delete it. So it shouldn't be possible for this error to happen. I forgot to mention, that its a single user setup, I've edited the question to reflect this. It doesn't look like a bug in my code.

Comment: @GerryColl That post is related to Delphi 5. I use Delphi XE. And its a new problem introduced with Windows 8.

Comment: sorry, I was reading on a tablet and missed the XE reference

Comment: I'd suggest testing some boundary conditions to see if you can simulate it. E.g. Make sure the code deletes the first record in the recordset, the last, and perhaps even the only record.